# Setting Ansible vars with set_fact results

Tags: ansible

Im running ansible 2.9.18 on RHEL7.

I am using hvac to retrieve usernames and passwords from a Hashicorp vault.

```
  vars:
    - creds: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=tst2/data/cisco token= url=http://10.80.23.81:8200') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: set Cisco creds
      set_fact:
        cisco: "{{ creds['data'] }}"

    - name: Get nxos facts
      nxos_command:
        username: "{{ cisco['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ cisco['password'] }}"
        commands: show ver
        timeout: 30
      register: ver_out
    - debug: msg="{{ ver_out.stdout }}"
```

But username and password are deprecated and I am trying to figure out how to pass the username, password as a "provider" variable. And this code doesn't work:

```
vars:
    asa_api:
      - creds: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=tst2/data/cisco token= url=http://10.80.23.81:8200') }}"
        set_fact:
          cisco: "{{ creds['data'] }}"
        username: "{{ cisco['username'] }}"
        password: "{{ cisco['password'] }}"

  tasks:
      - name: show run
        asa_command:
          commands: show run
          provider: "{{ asa_api }}"
        register: run
        become: yes
        tags:
          - show_run
```

I cannot figure how syntax for making this work. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Just as an add-on to my below answer: What you have tried "doens't work" `set_fact` is a module which must be used in a task. Here you are basically creatin a list containing a key called `set_fact` and a subkey `cisco` declaring a value from a variable `creds` that does not exist (i.e. your are creating `asa_api[0].creds` and you cannot self reference an element on declaration in yaml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is a generic answer. I do not have any network device to test this fully so you might have to adapt a bit after reading the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/platform_nxos.html)

---

Your are taking this the wrong way. You don't need `set_fact` at all and both method you are trying to use (user/pass or `provider` dict) are actually deprecated. Ansible treats you network device as any host and will use the available user and password you have configured if they exist.

In the following example, I'm assuming your playbook only targets network devices and that the login/pass stored in your vault is the same on all devices.

```yaml
- name: Untested network device connection configuration demo
  hosts: my_network_device_group

  vars:
    # This indicates which connection plugin to use. Default is ssh
    # An other possible value is httpapi. See above documentation link
    ansible_connection: network_cli
    
    vault_secret: tst2/data/cisco
    vault_token: verysecret
    vault_url: http://10.80.23.81:8200
    vault_options: "secret={{ vault_secret }} token={{ vault_token }} url={{ vault_url }}"

    creds: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', vault_options).data }}"
    
    # These are the user and pass used for connection.
    ansible_user: "{{ creds.username }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ creds.password }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Get nxos version
      nxos_command:
        commands: show ver
        timeout: 30
      register: ver_cmd
   
    - name: show version
      debug:
        msg: "NXOS version on {{ inventory_hostname }} is {{ ver_cmd.stdout }}"

    - name: An other task to play on targets
      debug:
        msg: "Task played on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Rather than `vars` at play level, you can store this information in your inventory for all hosts or for a specific group, even for each host. See [how to organise your group and host variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) if you want to use that feature.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks so much for your input. I am still trying to figure out "connection: local" versus "ansible_connection: network_cli". When I used "network_cli" I got a message that ansible could not "automatically determine the os". I reverted to "local" and the playbook works.

Comment: `(ansible_)connection: local` basically connects to your localhost => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html#running-against-localhost. The ansible prefix depends on wether it is a play level option or a variable.

Comment: Right, that both makes sense and is confusing. I have "connection: local" and ansible successfully SSH's to my cisco boxes and does what I ask. "connection: network_cli" fails.